# Get a textbox to display days difference between 2 date pickers

Tags: c#

I have 2 datetime pickers and i want to display number of days between them on a text box if a user selects a date.

The problem with my code is that it is not giving me correct answers and the `TimeSpan` doesn't seem to work.

When i choose different dates it gives me answer 10.999998008713 days instead of 11 days and I don't know if i need to do math roundup

```
    private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
          DateTime start = ArrivalDate.Value;
          DateTime finish = DepartureDate.Value;

          TimeSpan numberOfNights = finish-start;
          double TotalDays= numberOfNights.Days;
          txtBoxNum.Text = (numberOfNights.ToString());
   }

   private void ArrivalDate_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       DepartureDate.Value = ArrivalDate.Value.AddDays(1);
   }

   private void DepartureDate_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (DepartureDate.Value < ArrivalDate.Value)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Cannot be less than previous date");
           DepartureDate.Value = ArrivalDate.Value.AddDays(1);
           snip...
       }
   }
```

Comment: What seems to be your issue?

Comment: You're halfway there. You have some code, but you need a question :D

Comment: Hi Welcome to StackOverflow. are you getting any error? if yes then could you please mention?

Comment: I wish i explained fully at the top but i was limited to 50 words so i couldnt fit my question/problem proper.. I have 2 datetime pickers and i want to display number of days between them on a text box if a user selects a date.. the problem with my code is that its not giving me correct answers and the time span doesnt seem to work.. i dont know where im going wrong thats why i asked for assistance

Comment: @CliveCarl, I have edited your question. The title is supposed to give a brief overview, the question area is where you should add the relevant info to the question itself. Jon Skeet has a great checklist for asking questions here on SO (http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) or you can check the Help section (http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: possible duplicate of [using 2 datepickers to display days difference in a textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776783/using-2-datepickers-to-display-days-difference-in-a-textbox)

Answer (score 1):

> i dont know if i need to do math roundup

Neither do we. 10.999998008713 days is about 10 days, 23 hours, 59 minutes and 59 seconds. Do you want to count that as 11 days? If so what about 10 days, 23 hours, 59 minutes and 58 seconds? At some point you are going to have to decide what the cutoff between 10 days and 11 days is. This probably depends on your business rules and we don't know that.

Also, `numberOfNights.Days` is the day component of your `numberOfNights` value; so for November 4 2013 that would be 4. Are you sure that's what you want? You don't want `numberOfNights.TotalDays`, which would be the elapsed time between your `finish` and `start` in days?

Comment: Dour High Arch thanks dude, i wanted it to display 11 but its working now.. all appreciated

Comment: @CliveCarl, since this answer helped you, you should a) vote it up, *and* b) mark it as answered (the green checkmark)

Comment: @ Nathan Koop, im knew on this site i tried voting up but it says " Vote up requires 15 Reputation" so i cant do nothing interms of voting up and marking as read

Answer (score 0):

this one did the trick

```
          int TotalDays= numberOfNights.Days;
          txtBoxNum.Text = ((int)Math.Ceiling(numberOfNights.TotalDays)).ToString();
```