# using 2 datepickers to display days difference in a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 datetime pickers and i want to display number of days between them on a text box if a user selects a date.. the problem with my code is that its not giving me correct answers and the time span doesnt seem to work.. i dont know where im going wrong thats why i asked for assistance.
I hope that explained better, please bear with me, its my first time to be on this site so im not familiar with the controls, sending stuff and updating
When i choose different dates it gives me answer 10.999998008713 days instead of 11 days and i dont know if i need to do math roundup

```
 private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        


          DateTime start = ArrivalDate.Value;
          DateTime finish = DepartureDate.Value;

          TimeSpan numberOfNights = finish-start;

          double TotalDays= numberOfNights.Days;
          txtBoxNum.Text = (numberOfNights.ToString());
   }

   private void ArrivalDate_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       DepartureDate.Value = ArrivalDate.Value.AddDays(1);
   }

   private void DepartureDate_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // setting messagebox to a sensible default message if no date or wrong date picked

       if (DepartureDate.Value < ArrivalDate.Value)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Cannot be less than previous date");
           DepartureDate.Value = ArrivalDate.Value.AddDays(1);

       }

       else
       {
           double Days = (DepartureDate.Value - ArrivalDate.Value).TotalDays;
           txtBoxNum.Text = Days.ToString();
           return;
```

Comment: I see you are new to SO.  Just to let you know, you should updated your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19775500/2145211), rather than asking a new one if it is for the same issue.  You may also want to read [ask]

Comment: TimeSpan class is what you want.

Comment: `DateTime start = ArrivalDate.Value.Date;DateTime finish = DepartureDate.Value.Date;` Try this

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but its displaying and answer like 10.00:00:00 instead of 10 days, do you know why this is?

Comment: It is a timespan. You've to use `TotalDays.ToString()` instead of `numberOfNights.ToString()`

Answer (score 2):

You need to get only the date part from your date picker:

```
DateTime start = ArrivalDate.Value.Date;
DateTime finish = DepartureDate.Value.Date;
```

Otherwise you also get time which interferes with your calculations.

Also, to display number of days as integer, use:

```
int TotalDays = numberOfNights.Days;  // Days is int anyway
txtBoxNum.Text = TotalDays.ToString();
```

Or simply

```
txtBoxNum.Text = numberOfNights.Days.ToString();
```

---

You can actually put the whole code into one line:

```
txtBoxNum.Text = new TimeSpan(DepartureDate.Value.Date.Ticks - ArrivalDate.Value.Date.Ticks).Days.ToString();
```